# Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight geofencing

Tags: c#, silverlight, geolocation, windows-phone-8.1, geofencing

I'm trying to develop a geofencing application for windows phone 8.1 silverlight. I have already developed an app in Windows Phone 8.1 (not Silverlight). following is that code;

```
private async void MonitorOnGeofenceStateChanged(GeofenceMonitor sender, object args)
    {

        //IReadOnlyCollection<GeofenceStateChangeReport> reports = GeofenceMonitor.Current.ReadReports();
        var reports = sender.ReadReports();
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, () =>
        {
            foreach (GeofenceStateChangeReport changeReport in reports)
            {
                if (changeReport.NewState == GeofenceState.Entered)
                {
                    Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, async () =>
                        {
                            MessageDialog dialog = new MessageDialog("u re in the location");
                            await dialog.ShowAsync();
                        });
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

But when I try this code in silverlight 8.1, It gives me an error in `Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.High, async () =>`

So I tried replacing it with `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>`. But then geaofencing notification doesn't show up. I couldn't find a working solution for this problem...

Comment: You don't need use one dispatcher call inside the other, one outer dispatcher.RunAsync call is enough. Which one is bothering you exactly, what type of error are you getting?

Comment: RunAsync method is not available in windows phone 8.1 Silverlight. But without that geofencing nortifications doesn't show up. error is;
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher doesn't contain a definition for for 'RunAsync' and no extension method 'RunAsync' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher' could be found.